# accessing mat pixels in native

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, native

i am trying to access and modify mat pixels in native, but i cannot get rid of errors.
my function is:

```
`extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3Native_FindFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba)
{
    Mat* pMatGr=(Mat*)addrGray;
    Mat* pMatRgb=(Mat*)addrRgba;
    vector<KeyPoint> v;
int i=0;

uchar* pixel = addrRgba.data;
for(int i = 0; i < Mat.rows * Mat.cols; ++i)
{
    // access pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2] here
    pixel += 3; // move to next pixel
}

}

}
`
```

and it is called by:

FindFeatures(mGrayMat.getNativeObjAddr(), mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());

from java

my errors are

`"field 'data' cannot be resolved", "field 'rows' cannot be resolved"`

help would be very appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mat.rows` should be `pMatGr->rows`, `Mat.cols` should `pMatGr->cols`, `addrRgba.data` should be `pMatRgb->data`.

Comment: Well, I'm not making any promises about that.

Comment: no need to promise, it worked with the corrections you wrote, exept pMatGr should be pMatRgb of course.